# Is it possible too convert a string to char in Bash and do operations similar to what can be done in C?

Tags: bash

I know that in Bash everything is a string.

But I have some variables representing a number between 0 and 255 that I got from other sources, for example 123 which is a string of length 3, and I want to "pack it" in one byte (instead of 3). I also want to do additions/substractions on such bytes (so it has to be modulo 256 for overflows).

Basically what I want to do is like the char type in C.

What it is the best way to do it Bash?

Comment: You can't do this in bash, because some bytes aren't valid strings. Most obviously, zero: the zero (or "null") byte cannot exist in a C-string (because it delimits the end of the string), so it cannot be stored in a variable or passed as an argument. Also, numbers 128-255 aren't valid UTF-8, so they may cause trouble in some situations. You're much better off using bash's normal representation, and converting to/from binary on output/input.

Comment: So you mean a Bash variable cannot hold arbitrary strings of bytes, but only strings of "interpretable" bytes like letters... How can i then convert the 3-byte string "128" for example into one byte (10000000) and put in stdout (for example to redirect in a file) since i can't put in a variable ?

Comment: Check out the `chr()` function(s) in [BashFAQ #71](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) (but note that the `ord()` function won't work on arbitrary bytes, for the reasons I gave). Alternately, you could produce hex and run it through `xxd -r -p` to get binary (and for input, run it through `xxd -p` and then convert hex to decimal).

Comment: This answers my question about the "packing" thing. I wonder if there is a program that could do computations on such bytes (e.g if i give the bytes 10000000 and 00000001 to it in its stdin, it returns in stdout the byte10000001), in other words do calculations like the type Int in languages such as C.

Comment: This really sounds like you should be using something other than bash. Maybe just for parts of the project, maybe for the whole thing. But bash just isn't suited for doing binary arithmetic and I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is a weakly typed language – you don't need to do anything special with a variable containing ASCII decimal numbers, as it will automatically be converted to an integer value as soon as you actually try to do integer arithmetic with it.

```
var="123"

let var+=42

(( var -= 42 ))

echo $(( var + 7 ))
```

Though you can be explicit and declare a variable as an integer, but that doesn't change much (mainly it makes assignment to that variable automatically parse arithmetic expressions even without using 'let'):

```
declare -i var=123
```

However, Bash does not have a 'char' or 'byte' type – signed 32/64-bit 'int' is the *only* numeric type it has. So you'll need to handle everything else manually.

Additions mod 256 can be written as, literally, addition mod 256:

```
(( var = (var + 789) % 256 ))
```

I'm less sure about subtraction, since bash integers are always signed, but I guess this would be one way to do it on most architectures:

```
(( var = (var - 345) & 255 ))
```

I would recommend using something else than bash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't exactly what I want, I should have given more explanations. I am writing a bash script because i pipeline many programs that encode numbers differently. A program A might output the number 128 as a string (so 3 bytes) but I need to feed it to a program B who interprets bytes directly as numbers (so the string "128" has to be converted to a string of length 1 as the byte 10000000 before being piped in B with |)

Comment: I think what I want to do is equivalent to scanf in C, but I want to use bash because i'm pipeling programs so it sounds more natural

Comment: You're connecting the programs and pipes using bash -- this has nothing to with writing the filter programs themselves in bash. The filters do not actually deal with pipelining, and practically nobody writes them in bash -- all the common ones such as grep or sed are written in C, etc.